# Direct ethernet connection with automatic IP allocation - how to get the opposite node IP?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

I am trying to connect 2 PCs directly with ethernet cable. One running Linux, acting as home server and it's headless, the other is a normal Windows laptop. Lets assume that both run some kind of IP auto-configuration; on Windows APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing), on Linux assume something like avahi-autoipd. Let's assume that that everything work correctly. APIPA, to my best knowledge, assigns random IP from 169.254.x.x range; I assume that avahi-autoipd does the same.

Question is: how can I get the IP address of the opposite node?

Lets assume that the opposite node, the Linux box, is headless so I cannot simply go there and read it there. Also it has no other network or other communication interface so I cannot, say, ssh there by the side channel and read it.

Comment: IP scanner is one option. But the range is quite wide. I am trying it right now and it take __ages__ ..like hours. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could IPv6 somewhat help?

Comment: If you're feeling lucky, you could try pinging the broadcast address of the 256 /24s that make up 169.254.0.0/16. Some IP implementations respond to broadcast pings, others don't.  Ping the first one a few times, then either note the replies (if any) or check your ARP table (if not).  Even an implementation that doesn't respond to pings **has** to respond to an ARP request.  If no joy, then move on and ping the broadcast address of the next /24.  This may or may not work, but you might get a result faster than a brute-force scan of the entire /16.

Comment: Hi @JimL That sounds interesting. Could you make it into a proper post? How the ping command would exactly look? How to check ARP table? Ideally using Windows tools but I can dual-boot to Linux too.